# Specifically remove files starting with ._ using terminal

Tags: shell, filenames

I uploaded my source code to SVN repository.

After committing I found many files starting with ._filename.

How can I remove all those files starting with *._filename*?

I have so many subfolders and each subfolder has same problem.It would be better for me to verify that only those files which match a particular pattern are deleted. So kindly help

Comment: switch to git and use [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "._*" -print
```

This will *find and display the names* of all the files matching the filename globbing pattern `._*` in the current directory, or in any of its subdirectories.

To remove them, change `-print` to `-delete`, or just add `-delete` to the end if you want to see what gets deleted.

Comment: You might want to add a filesize check. All those files are about 4kb. I've recently deleted a few files to many with a similar command. The ~4kb check would've saved me from that.

Answer (score 8):

The command to remove all files which starts with `._` is:

```
rm ._*
```

Before running `rm` command which will delete all files which match the pattern `._*`, I'd suggest running the `ls` command to provide the list of all files which match the pattern:

```
ls -lsa ._*
```

Comment: I want to do that in sub directories also ..how can i achieve that..Thanks for the ls command.

Comment: @Jeeva You need to run `rm` with `-r` switch, [as detailed in `man rm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html).